# Обновление UI с помощью LiveData (обновление ссылки)

Tags: android, kotlin, livedata, mvvm-android

Есть фрагмент с `RecyclerView`. При нажатии на кнопку удаления элемента (в элементе списка) или при добавлении элемента, нужно автоматически обновить список (перезаписать). Опытным путём определил, что `LiveData` основывается на ссылках, а не значениях. И обновление произойдёт только после создания новой ссылки. На сколько корректно использовать такое решение для аналогичных задач и есть ли более лаконичное решение?

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel.listOfPhotoUri.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        photoAdapter.updateData(it.toList())
    }
}
```

```
// ViewModel

fun addUri(uri: Uri) {
    _listOfPhotoUri.value?.add(uri)
    rewriteLiveData()
}

fun removeUri(uri: Uri) {
    _listOfPhotoUri.value?.remove(uri)
    rewriteLiveData()
}

private fun rewriteLiveData(): MutableSet<Uri> {
    val newValue = _listOfPhotoUri.value
    _listOfPhotoUri.value?.let {
        _listOfPhotoUri.value = it
    }
    return newValue ?: mutableSetOf()
}
```

Comment: _listOfPhotoUri.value = _listOfPhotoUri.value тоже нормальное решение. если вы работаете со списками, только так и над работать. ну и конечно же, это ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО должно быть во ВьюМодели и инкапсулировано.

Comment: `_listOfPhotoUri.value = ???` - в котлине это выглядит не очевидным, но это вызов сеттера `setValue(T value)`, который и приводит к оповещению слушателя. То есть решающее значение имеет сам вызов сеттера, а не изменение данных.